# Why am I getting AssertionError in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Could you advise, what can we do in the situation, when tests are running OK, but in the end of the tests there are errors and a long stack trace in Selenium?

```
package com.example.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class AddGroupTests {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium-java-3.12.0\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddNewGroup() throws Exception {
    openMainPage();
    findFrame();
    logIn();
    goToGroupPage();
    fillFormAndSubmit("Group1", "Head", "Foot");
    verifyTextOnPage();
    returnToGroupsPage();
  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddNewEmptyGroup() throws Exception {
    openMainPage();
    findFrame();
    logIn();
    goToGroupPage();
    fillFormAndSubmit("", "", "");
    verifyTextOnPage();
    returnToGroupsPage();
  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  }

private void verifyTextOnPage() {
    try {
      assertEquals("A new group has been entered into the address book.return to the group page", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
}

private void returnToGroupsPage() {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("group page")).click();
}

private void fillFormAndSubmit(String name, String header, String footer) {
    clickAndClear("group_name", "group_name");
    driver.findElement(By.name("group_name")).sendKeys(name);
    clickAndClear("group_header", "group_header");
    driver.findElement(By.name("group_header")).sendKeys(header);
    clickAndClear("group_footer", "group_footer");
    driver.findElement(By.name("group_footer")).sendKeys(footer);
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
}

private void goToGroupPage() {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Группы")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("new")).click();
}

private void logIn() {
    driver.findElement(By.name("user")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("user")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("pass");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Войти']")).click();
}

private void findFrame() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("demobody"));
}

private void openMainPage() {
    driver.get("https://www.softaculous.com/softaculous/demos/PHP_Address_Book");
}

private void clickAndClear(String locator, String locator2) {
    driver.findElement(By.name(locator)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name(locator2)).clear();
}

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

And the stack trace is like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...to the address book.[]return to the group ...> but was:<...to the address book.[
]return to the group ...>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at com.example.tests.AddGroupTests.tearDown(AddGroupTests.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:83)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Tried to erase all imports and to fix red problem one by one, still, failures exist. I see the message: AssertionError, but unable to locate the problem. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the actual error message?

Comment: You are trying to import all elements of a class. You can only do that to a static import or package.

Comment: Post an [mcve]. Please [don't post screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. Post the actual (full) error message.

Comment: It looks like you are using Eclipse. Delete all your imports. You will now see a lot of red squiggles under code that Eclipse doesn't recognize. Hover over one and you will see a popup with quick fixes. Click on the quick fix that imports the relevant library. Continue this process until all red squiggles are gone.

Comment: You should try to debug your tearDown() method because looking to your screenshot with stack trace problem is there and after this add row that cause this exception to your question to get proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

`AssertionError` happens when an Assertion (the thing you're trying to verify) fails. When you get an `AssertionError`, it doesn't mean that your code fails, but it means that the condition you were checking wasn't true.

Now usually Assertion errors mean that there's some problem with stuff you're testing. But often it's because there's something wrong with the way you're testing things.

In your example, the stack trace is helpful:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...to the address 
book.[]return to the group ...> but was:<...to the address book.[
]return to the group ...>
```

You tried to compare two strings but they were different. What was different? It's highlighted: in your expected string (`"A new group has been entered into the address book.return to the group page"` in `verifyTextOnPage` test), "return" goes right after the dot, there's no whitespace. The real text apparently has a newline character between them ("return" continues on a new line). That's why the comparison failed, and that's why you get an `AssertionError`.

Please do not fear error messages and try to understand them: they provide valuable information.